# PHP sessions not working in my server after refresh

Tags: php, session

I tried to use sessions, but are not working, so I tested them with

```
$_SESSION['one']        = 'one';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I refreshed the browser, it works `Array ( [one] => one )`

I commented the `$_SESSION['one'] = 'one';`, I refreshed, then the result is empty, session lost, my settings are the info file. The sessions folder has some session files but no content:

```
ls -l /var/lib/php/sessions/

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Nov 17 21:59 sess_v0maohltlu0lnmq6fgpo8kn2ee
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63 Nov 17 22:02 sess_vbjg2ggj2jkji51sfjnq3ivisl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Nov 17 22:12 sess_vkqf3hu5rt4q8ltv1m9evkp6h5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63 Nov 17 22:08 sess_vn4i02e8jfg1tadn9fvaj2ppru
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Nov 17 22:04 sess_vvmc71tntma9bpjqp7fjei65pd
```

Server settings

[image: img_server_settings]